# Programmatically create an <ui:include src="..."/> in backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

In a JSF page I have:

```
<h:form id="form">
   <h:panelGroup id="content" layout="block"/>
</h:form>
```

In a Java SessionScoped bean i have a method:

```
public void fillContent()
{
   UIComponent content = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form:content");
   content.getChildren().clear();
   content.getChildren().add(/*New <ui:include src="Page.xhtml"/>*/);
}
```

What is the Java code to insert the `<ui:include src="Page.xhtml"/>` as `content` children?
Where I can find the list for the mapping of all the JSF Java names?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ui:include is implemented as a tag handler. This means it is evaluated and executed when component tree is built and there is no corresponding UIComponent class.

To achieve your goal you would have to use the facelets api like javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletContext#includeFacelet, after preserving reference to the faceletContext which is accessible during tree construction. This is not a straightforward approach and I would strongly recommend rephrasing your problem and looking for another solution.

I don't know any official guide with tag-component/handler mapping, I am sure some books like "Core Java Server Faces" will help with this though.

You can try to do this in facelets to begin with, something like:

```
<h:form id="form">
  <ui:include src="#{content.path}"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I don't think primefaces offers anything extra to solve this. Why you have to alter your view in a programmatic way? Doing this in facelets to begin with should be much easier.

Comment: How? Can you explain me, please?

Comment: I used it, it works "just a bit", I mean that loads the page (all in Ajax, no refreshes) but the page content doesn't work, and when I reload the page it throws a ClassCastException: Cannot Cast primefaces.AjaxBehavior to java.util.List. Don't know how to do it working properly :(

Comment: Your question does not contain enough detail to answer it properly I'm afraid. If all included variants are known up front the safest bet would be creating a ui:fragment section for each and control its "renderer" attribute through an EL expression.